# How to use database name dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get all table names in SQL Server. To do this I use this code:

```
select TABLE_NAME  
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

I need use dynamic database name. To do this I tried to use this code:

```
Declare @dbName varchar(50)='Learn'

use @dbname
go

select TABLE_NAME  
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

But it does not work. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dbName varchar(50)='Learn'
EXEC ('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ' +@dbName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES');
```

OR SIMPLY:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM Learn.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 2):

Create this stored procedure in master db and call it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE custom_query_executor
    @dbName     VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query_string nvarchar(4000);

    SET @query_string = 'select TABLE_NAME from ' + CAST(@dbName AS NVARCHAR) +'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query_string;
END
```

OR you can try this

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(50);
SET @dbName = 'Learn';

SET @query_string = 'select TABLE_NAME from ' + CAST(@dbName AS NVARCHAR) +'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
Declare @dbName varchar(50)='Learn'
SET @sql='
use '+@dbname+'
go

select TABLE_NAME  
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
exec (@sql)
```